# Can't extend/override parent "move" element

Tags: magento2

In catalog_product_view.xml in the parent theme there is this, just copied up to one line past the line Im trying to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-">
                <container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" />
                <container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" />
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.social.links" />
        <move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
```

But I need to move it somewhere else in my child theme, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.social.links" />
    </body>
</page>
```

but it doesn't want to extend the parent and as soon as I delete the line from the parent layout file it moves it right where I need it to go. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

It is in the Infortis > Ultimo theme

The parent xml file:
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

The child xml file
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/childtemp/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out the problem. In the theme table in the database the theme was set to "1" instead of "0" like all the rest of the themes.. Im not sure how it got set to 1, but I believe that means Virtual instead of Physical.. which Im not even sure what that means either, but that solved the problem. Now my child xml extends the parent xml just fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you located the correct path for the layout extend in your custom theme? Seems to me that the fallback is the issue.

Comment: Yes, because as soon as I remove the parent theme line, then my child theme line takes over.. which means my child theme, at least for the "move" element is not overriding the parent theme. Maybe "move" can not be overridden?

Comment: The first thing is, that you are actually not overriding, you're extending the layout. So perhaps is something about the order of the XML handlers. You can move whatever you want on your own theme based on the blank or vendor/module layout structures.

So to start, can you edit your post with more specs? Like paths of each file, vendor and your theme, and an extra piece of the XML you are trying to extend from the parent.

Comment: There you go, hopefully that's more helpful, thank you for the suggestion and the verbiage. Im not sure why I typed override!

Comment: Awesome! let me take a look!

Comment: Mmmm, seems to be the product itself, are you in a simple, configurable one? or a downloadable/virtual? Because the latest ones had a different XML inside the Magento structure with other movements. On the other hand, I don't know for sure if they are doing something else besides those moves in your custom theme. If your parent were the Blank theme from Magento, it should work, and if your theme is just a child inherited one, it should too. Check the other product_view.xml from every type of products to see. It is weird, it should work :(

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah like I said when I remove the line from the parent xml file then the child takes over and works just fine, so it's correct, but that's why I was thinking maybe a child "move" does not override a parent "move"?

Comment: It does actually. That is why it is odd.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the problem in my answer, it was a very strange one and Im still unsure of why it makes a difference, but it fixed the problem!